# Will factory-reset delete custom downloaded app's folders?

Tags: factory-reset, tablet

I need to know something. For example an app like Telegram that is a custom downloaded app uses two ways of keeping the data,

1. in the cache folder and since it is stored in /data

   - it will be removed
2. internal storage>Telegram>Telegram Images/audio/...

   - will this folders be deleted too?

btw I'm using an Android Tablet, I don't know if it makes any difference.

Comment: I don't know about factory resets performed from a stock recovery, but resets performed from **CWM** and **TWRP** will leave the internal storage (**/data/media**) be, unless you explicitly format it.

Comment: I mean the factory reset option in the android tablet settings..

Comment: +1 because it has concerned me in the past... Welcome to Android.SE!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it would delete.

Although if you have a Google account signed in to the device, and the app is written in a way, the app data may be backed up to your Google Drive and can be restored the next time it is installed (given this feature isn't turned off in settings.)

*some older devices/android versions may give you the option [not to clear internal storage.](http://forums.androidcentral.com/asus-fonepad/302368-will-factory-reset-recovery-delete-internal-storage.html)*

Comment: Thank you so much. Telegram doesn't have this feature, does it?

Comment: I'm not sure tbh. I think later android versions do this automatically? Apps can opt-out, rather than the old way of opting-in. So it's likely the app supports it.

Comment: I think it has its own cloud servers. Thank you soooo much.

Comment: you're welcome. Please mark as answer if it solved the issue. thanks :)

Comment: I am so sorry to ask again but there is an option for the factory reset that can keep internal storage untouched.. and also when I manually uninstall the app the latter isn't deleted. I mean if we expect factory reset to delete this folder just because the app is uninstalled, it won't be. 
so are you sure that by factory reset both the cache and the other folders related to that app and are not in /data will be deleted?

Comment: Actually the later models doesn't give you that option. (my devices doesn't) If you have an older version, or a custom ROM, it may give you the option. (See http://forums.androidcentral.com/asus-fonepad/302368-will-factory-reset-recovery-delete-internal-storage.html)Although I wouldn't rely on it. Always take a back up. It can't hurt.